# Wrap Razor Page with Dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Basically I would like to wrap some dynamically generated HTML around the output of a Razor page.  For purposes of this example, lets assume `string wrapper` is receiving a dynamic HTML string from the database.  However it will ALWAYS include `<div id="content"></div>`

Consider this `OnGetAsync` method from **example.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
        //wrapper will be dynamically assigned from database
        //but will also ALWAYS contain div id=content

        string wrapper = @"<html><head></head><body><h1>HELLO</h1>" &_
                "<div id="content"></div></body></html>"

        return Page();
    }
```

**example.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model ExampleModel

@section CSS {

    <style type="text/css">
        .midnight {
            color: #ccc;
        }
    </style>

}

<p>this is a test</p>
```

After `return Page();` executes, I would like to take the resulting HTML somehow and inject it into the wrapper code within the content div.

Ideally, the resulting **output** would be this:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>HELLO</h1>
   <div id="content"> 
      <!-- injected from OnGetAsync() -->         
      <!-- omitted for brevity
           more code including @section CSS -->
      <p>this is a test</p>
      <!-- END injected from OnGetAsync() -->  
   </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

How would you accomplish this with Razor Pages, asp.net core 2.2 and/or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery to move the text to `content` div after page load :

Code behind :

```
public string Content { get; set; } 

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    //wrapper will be dynamically assigned from database
    //but will also ALWAYS contain div id=content

    string wrapper = @"<html><head></head><body><h1>HELLO</h1><div id='content'></div></body></html>";
    Content = wrapper;

    return Page();
}
```

Razor page :

```
<p id="orginalConent">this is a test</p>

@Html.Raw(@Model.Content)

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var orginalConent = $("#orginalConent");
            $('#content').append($('<p>').text(orginalConent.text()));
            orginalConent.remove();           
        })

    </script>

}
```